# JFrame Components Loading Slowly

Tags: java, performance, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm building a keyboard for an assignment at school, and I've noticed an issue I've never had before.  My `JFrame` is opening right away, but the `JPanels` within it, mainly the content pane, are loading in slowly after the fact.  This gives an unfinished feel to the project, and I'm looking for a fix.  They do load eventually, but I'm looking for a way to make the frame and the panels open at the same time.

```
public class main {

    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel panel, option, keys;
    public static JButton A, B, C, D, E, F, G, A3, C3, D3, F3, G3;
    public static AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    public static Clip clip;

    public static void start() {
        frame = new JFrame("PIANO");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        option = new JPanel();
        option.setOpaque(true);
        option.setSize(new Dimension(700, 100));
        option.setLocation(0, 0);
        option.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        panel.add(option);

        keys = new JPanel();
        keys.setOpaque(true);
        keys.setSize(new Dimension(700, 400));
        keys.setLocation(0, 100);
        keys.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(keys);

        C3 = new JButton();
        C3.setSize(new Dimension(60, 190));
        C3.setLocation(70, 0);
        C3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        C3.setOpaque(true);
        C3.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {

            try {
                audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C_s.wav").getAbsoluteFile());

                // create clip reference
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                // open audioInputStream to the clip
                clip.open(audioInputStream);

                clip.start();
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        });
        keys.add(C3);

        D3 = new JButton();
        D3.setSize(new Dimension(60, 190));
        D3.setLocation(170, 0);
        D3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        D3.setOpaque(true);
        D3.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {

            try {
                audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("D_s.wav").getAbsoluteFile());

                // create clip reference
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                // open audioInputStream to the clip
                clip.open(audioInputStream);

                clip.start();
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        });
        keys.add(D3);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and ..

Comment: .. borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Further tips: * Don't use `static` for GUI components, and otherwise only use it if you can explain why it needs to be static (from a design POV, not 'fixing compiler errors') * Create and start the GUI on the EDT. * `..setOpaque(true);` that is the normal state for components, no need to state it for each one. * Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the ..

Comment: .. [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. * The `Clip` objects should (likely) be loaded on construction and simply started in the action listener. * Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to the issue, though I'm still not quite sure as to what caused it to execute slowly.  As soon as I added a component to the other JPanel, option, my program ran exactly as I wanted it to.  It didn't stall out like it was.

```
public class main {

public static JFrame frame;
public static JPanel panel, option, keys;
public static JButton A, B, C, D, E, F, G, A3, C3, D3, F3, G3;
public static AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
public static Clip clip;
public static boolean octave1, octave2;

public static void start() {
    frame = new JFrame("PIANO");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setOpaque(true);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);

    option = new JPanel();
    option.setOpaque(true);
    option.setSize(new Dimension(700, 100));
    option.setLocation(0, 0);
    option.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    panel.add(option);

    //ADDED NEW

    oct1 = new JRadioButton("Low Octave");
    oct1.setSelected(true);
    oct1.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {

        oct2.setSelected(false);
        octave1 = true;
        octave2 = false;

    });
    option.add(oct1);

    oct2 = new JRadioButton("High Octave");
    oct2.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {

        oct1.setSelected(false);
        octave1 = false;
        octave2 = true;

    });

    //END OF NEW

    keys = new JPanel();
    keys.setOpaque(true);
    keys.setSize(new Dimension(700, 400));
    keys.setLocation(0, 100);
    keys.setLayout(null);
    panel.add(keys);

    C3 = new JButton();
    C3.setSize(new Dimension(60, 190));
    C3.setLocation(70, 0);
    C3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    C3.setOpaque(true);
    C3.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {

        try {
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C_s.wav").getAbsoluteFile());

            // create clip reference
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

            // open audioInputStream to the clip
            clip.open(audioInputStream);

            clip.start();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    });
    keys.add(C3);

    D3 = new JButton();
    D3.setSize(new Dimension(60, 190));
    D3.setLocation(170, 0);
    D3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    D3.setOpaque(true);
    D3.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {

        try {
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("D_s.wav").getAbsoluteFile());

            // create clip reference
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

            // open audioInputStream to the clip
            clip.open(audioInputStream);

            clip.start();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    });
    keys.add(D3);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should always use Threads for heavy tasks like loading files or read from a database so they can run on the background without affecting your GUI. I hope this can help you:

```
new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            C3.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {

                try {
                    audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C_s.wav").getAbsoluteFile());

                    // create clip reference
                    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                    // open audioInputStream to the clip
                    clip.open(audioInputStream);

                    clip.start();
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    //Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            });
        }

    }.run();

//You can leave your listeners on the same lines as your the example

new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            D3.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {

                try {
                    audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("D_s.wav").getAbsoluteFile());

                    // create clip reference
                    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                    // open audioInputStream to the clip
                    clip.open(audioInputStream);

                    clip.start();
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    //Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            });
        }

    }.run();
```

Comment: While your statements are correct, merely moving the call to addActionListener into a new thread will make no difference.  It’s not like the listener is actually being called at that point.

Comment: (1-) adding an ActionListner to a button will not affect the performance. Executing the code in the ActionListner when the button is clicked can affect performance. So long running code in the ActionListener should be executed in a separate Thread.